why are the results of the 2 streams different?
The Stream API supports lazy operations, so I understand that it calculates vertically.
However, the results are different depending on the location of the limit method. Why does the operation continue even after getting the limit amount of results when limit is used after filter?
// code 1
int sum = IntStream.range(1, 101)
                .map(i -> {
                    System.out.format("map : %d \n",i);
                    return i * i;
                })
                .limit(5)
                .filter(i -> {
                    System.out.format("filter : %d\n",i);
                    return i<20;
                })
                .sum();
        System.out.println(sum);

// result
map : 1 
filter : 1
map : 2 
filter : 4
map : 3 
filter : 9
map : 4 
filter : 16
map : 5 
filter : 25
30


// code 2
int sum = IntStream.range(1, 101)
                .map(i -> {
                    System.out.format("map : %d \n",i);
                    return i * i;
                })
                .filter(i -> {
                    System.out.format("filter : %d\n",i);
                    return i<20;
                })
                .limit(5)
                .sum();
        System.out.println(sum);

// result
map : 1 
filter : 1
map : 2 
filter : 4
...
map : 97 
filter : 9409
map : 98 
filter : 9604
map : 99 
filter : 9801
map : 100 
filter : 10000
30

I thought the two results would be similar, but I wonder why there is a difference in the number of operations.

Since the filter conditional guarantees that the specified limit wont be reached it keeps taking in values.  This causes the map and the filter to see all the values from the source.  When the limit is placed directly after the map, the limit is quickly reached.
If you change the condition in the filter to i <= 25 (the fifth square), its output will be limited similar to the first one.

omg....... it's my big mistake. really appreciate it :)
